# Weird issue with android radio buttons

Tags: android, user-interface, radio-button, apk

I am trying to use radio buttons in a quiz android app . I have a weird problem while coding . when I choose first radio button as the first option, then I click on the NEXT button which shows next question and make 1st radio button setChecked(false) . After that for the 2nd question the 1st radio button is not working until I choose another radio button then it will be active and choose-able. This is obviously a problem in UI which I do like to get rid of with your kindness helps . Tnx in advance .

Comment: reset the UI before starting the 2nd question, best practice for `RadioButton` is to make one option checked by default

Comment: tnx but how can I reset the ui ?

Answer (score 0):

use radio groups. Following is simple tutorial :
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/radiogroup/android-radiogroup-example/

Comment: tnx but it didnot help me because my question is sth else.

Comment: ohh i get it what you need please set a default option checked and dont use setChecked(false). Just on pressing next obtain value and process it for your use.

Comment: oh tnx . It worked out ! I wanted to show the user a blank list of choices every time when a new question is shown .If you had any useful ideas I would appreciate it to know .